# The best plot for lists of bits in matplotlib

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I have a nominal data with two values (0 and 1) of 400 values. I have an actual and a predicted data of this type. My need is that I want to plot these nominal values of both actual and predicted ones on the same plot so that It will be easy to compare how good was the prediction as compared to actual values. Is there any good plot type that is elegant and informative enough ?

Comment: Do you even need plotting? You basically need only four numbers (number/fraction of good and false positives and negatives).

Comment: @leeladam so if you were to present this to a potential customer, What kind of presentation will be best (in terms of summarization and appealing graphics) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if we had some data, but how about an idea like this to get you started with `ggplot2`:

**EDIT** - updated to show discrete data. Red points and area flag *incorrect* predictions.

```
dd<-data.frame(obs=1:100,Pred=sample(0:1,100,TRUE),Act=sample(0:1,100,TRUE))

dd$diff<-abs(dd$Pred-dd$Act)
dd$cum<-cumsum(dd$diff)/dd$obs


ggplot(dd) + 
  geom_line(aes(obs,Pred),color="green",linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(obs,Act),color="blue",linetype=1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(obs,ymax=cum,ymin=0),fill="red",color="red",alpha=0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(obs,diff,fill=factor(-diff)),color="white", shape=22,size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: As I can see on your graph, you are plotting continuous data.But in my situation,these are only two discrete values(0 and 1) so how does this fit to your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really need is the presentation of the fraction of true positives and true negatives against false positives and false negatives. I don't think you need plotting here as you want to present only four numbers, but some visualization examples for this case can be found [here](http://res.illumina.com/images/truseq/figures/true_and_called_snps.jpg) and [here](http://www.nature.com/ki/journal/v75/n12/images/ki200992f1.jpg).